# Does Clara (Oswin Oswald) say "Run you clever boy, and Remember" or "Run you clever boy, and remember me"?

Tags: doctor-who

I like painting quotes on Canvases (Kinda weird, but I like it) and I really like this one; so I want to get it right. I tried looking this up but it came up with both so I was hoping someone else could help.

Comment: “Kinda weird, but I like it” — Jess, you’re in the right place.

Comment: If you come back,  you can accept the answer you feel best answers your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I believe that Run You Clever Boy and Remember is a mnemonic for RYCbCr, a format for encoding video color.

Answer (score 69):

### Both

In "Asylum of the Daleks," she says the first  version:

> DALEK: Human! Remember me.
>
> DOCTOR: Thank you.
>
> DALEK: Run!  (The
> Doctor runs as the bombardment starts.)
>
> [Room]
>
> OSWIN: **Run, you clever boy. And remember.**

She also says this in "The Snowmen":

> CLARA: Are you going back to your cloud?
>
> DOCTOR: No more cloud. Not now.
>
> CLARA: Why not?
>
> DOCTOR: It rained.
>
> CLARA: Run. **Run, you clever boy. And remember.**
>
> (The clock chimes midnight as Clara dies.)
>
> DIGBY: It's Christmas. Christmas Day.

This is also the long form of her Wi-Fi password in "The Bells of St. John":

> CLARA: It's asking me for a password.
>
> ANGIE: Is it okay if I go and see Nina? You can call her mum.
>
> CLARA: Sure. What's the password for the internet?
>
> ANGIE: R Y C B A R 1 2 3.
>
> CLARA: How am I supposed to remember that?

In "The Name of the Doctor," she says the second one:

> CLARA: If this works, get out of here as fast as you can. And spare me
> a thought now and then.
>
> DOCTOR: No, Clara...!
>
> CLARA: [Bravely facing the timesteam] In fact, you know what? [She
> turns to look at him] Run. **Run, you clever boy...and remember me.**

Note that the second form is in "The Name of the Doctor," the episode in which Clara splits into various copies of herself, as seen in all those previous episodes. As such, the variation from formula has thematic meaning: this is the real Clara.

Comment: It always kind of annoyed me, that modification. It was needed in context for the utterance to make any real sense, which just seemed like a lack of foresight. But the moment would have been more powerful had the "catchphrase" (however it was originally) not changed. I consider _"Run, you clever boy. And remember"_ to be the canonical version of the phrase (and the one that should be painted on a canvas). As an aside, the season finale made it even worse, with _"Run, you clever boy. And be a Doctor"_ which was necessary because he wasn't supposed to remember! Sigh.

Comment: Wait, so does that mean, the real Clara during the episode of splitting inside doctor's timeline used 'remember me' phrase while all other times its the already split and reincarnated versions of Clara trying to remind him of the original Clara by saying "remember'? So then it depends on whose quote you are using right? or it could even be that she is trying to remind him of different things in different episodes so it all comes down to the object of importance. its not a catchphrase like Geronimo that the doctor always uses in the same way.???

Comment: @Dev It's Doctor Who. Timey-wimey, things get weird.

Answer (score 2):

She says

> Run you clever boy... and remember

For example, you can see that scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epc-Z974eiQ).

For completeness, you have the following dialogue:

> OO: Then run...
>
> DW: What did you say?
>
> OO: I've taken out the force field. The Dalek above have begun their attack. Run!
>
> DW: Are you...?
>
> OO: I was Oswin Oswald. I fought the Daleks and I am Human! Remember me.
>
> DW: Thank you.
>
> OO: Run!
>
> *The Doctor runs*
>
> OO: **Run you clever boy... and remember.**

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Clara_Oswald#Quotes) (which I found by Googling what you posted) It's

> Run … run, you clever boy … and remember.

Wikiquote has this to say:

> Last words to the Doctor before dying, first as Oswin Oswald (in the Dalek Asylum), then as Clara Oswin Oswald (Victorian London), and then as Clara Oswald (21st century London)

I even found [the clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epc-Z974eiQ) for you so you can hear it yourself (it's near the end of the clip).